# Replicate a claim in a complete market

Tags: black-scholes, replication

Consider the Black-Scholes market wher $\sigma > 0$, and a claim paying $S_T^{\gamma}$ at time $T$, where $\gamma$ is some positive constant. How do I find the replicating portfolio of such a claim？

Comment: How do we interpret $\gamma$?

Comment: @wecandothis I think $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. These are power options with $K=0$.

Comment: Yeah so the payoff is then $\mathbb{X} = S^2(T)$. It seems that we miss some information but the pay off is then $S_T^{2} = S_0^{2} \exp{\gamma(r-\sigma)T + \gamma \sigma W_T} $

Comment: But there is no optionality so you can only price this claim?

Comment: FYI: Fixed $\LaTeX$ in comment above